# A new primality test for Proth primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Here is what I have observed.  $p = k2^n+1$ (a Proth number), $k$ is odd,

1. If $x^2+1$ mod p=0, has 2 solutions x=+- r mod p  , then p is prime,
2. If $x^2+1$ mod p=0,has more than 2 solutions or no solution , then p is composite,

Can this be a new primality test for Proth numbers or is it already known?

Numerical example:

$p = 37*2^{16}+1$ (a Proth prime),
$x^2+1$ mod p=0, has 2 solutions x=+- r mod p  ,

$p = 35*2^{16}+1$ (a Proth number),
$x^2+1$ mod p=0, has no solutions ,

$p = 33*2^{16}+1$ (a Proth number),
$x^2+1$ mod p=0, has 4 solutions,

Thank you.

Comment: how do you know it has exactly 2 solutions?

Comment: By computing numerical examples, trying wolfram alpha

Comment: but it's easier to factor a number than find the solutions of the eqution,in fact,the computer will factor the number first.

Comment: Just Asking if this is a valid primality test? Complexity is another thing.

Comment: Yes,it is.$p=1\pmod 4$ is prime iff $x^2=-1\pmod p$ has 2 solutions.

Comment: Where can I find the proof? Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some components of this are known in the sense that

1. $-1$ is a quadratic residue of any prime that is congruent to $1 \pmod{4}$ (see e.g. [Euler's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion)).
2. If $x^2\equiv y^2 \pmod{n}$ and $x\not\equiv \pm y \pmod{n}$ (that is: there are four or more solutions to $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{n}$ for some $a$) then $(x-y)(x+y)$ gives a non-trivial factorization of $n$ (see e.g. the [quadratic sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve)).
3. If $x^2\equiv -1 \pmod{mn}$ for $m>1,n>1$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ (any composite divisible by two different primes can be factored this way), then the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) gives us four solutions corresponding to the choices $x_i\equiv\pm x \pmod{m}$ and $x_i\equiv \pm x \pmod{n}$.

(These apply to all numbers $n=4i+1$, not just Proth numbers.)

But the remaining case is $n=p^j$ for some prime $p$, and here we find some counterexamples where there are exactly two solutions when $n$ is composite, e.g. $n=9*2^5+1=289$ has exactly two solutions $38^2\equiv 251^2\equiv -1 \pmod{289}$.

Comment: What if   $x^2+n$ mod p=0, has 2 solutions, can we also say p is prime?

Comment: Points 2 & 3 still apply, so if there are more than 2 solutions then p is composite. But if there are exactly 2 solutions p may still be a prime power. And for prime p there will be no solutions if $-n$ is not a quadratic residue mod p (which happens half the time).

Comment: it seems I need some detailed studying on this. Any pointers?

Comment: @Kurtul Many elementary number theory textbooks (e.g. Andrews) will have a chapter on quadratic residues and quadratic reciprocity that explicitly address the question of when $x^2+n\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ has solutions.